# Can a mono white with the option to use green mana or life to be transformed be used in a mono white deck?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I don't know the best way to word it in the title, but I have a mono white card that has the option to use green mana or life to transform the card. Now since the card color is white is it good to use in a mono white deck?

Comment: Are you talking about the card Tarkir Duneshaper?

Comment: Are you asking about the rules ("can it be used") or strategy suggestions ("is it a good idea")? The title of the question doesn't match the body there.

Comment: If you're talking about Commander or a close variant (Oathbreaker, Brawl, etc) note that those formats care about [color identity](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/54037/how-does-color-identity-work-in-commander), not color.

Answer (score 1):

As murgatroid99 said, I'll assume you are referring to [Tarkir Duneshaper](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tarkir%20Duneshaper). (To link to a card, type `[mtg:CardName]`.) But "is it good to use" isn't clear enough for a single answer.

If your question is "can I legally put the card into my mono-white deck":

- If you're playing any format but Commander, the answer is yes. In contrast to some card games like *Hearthstone*, *Magic* lets you put any card you want in a deck, even if your deck can't produce the colors of mana necessary to cast or activate it.
- If you're playing Commander, the answer is no. In Commander, all cards must have a color identity that is a subset of your commander's color identity (see rule 903.4). If your commander is mono-white, then the Phyrexian green mana symbol in Tarkir Duneshaper is a symbol not in the commander's identity, so you can't include it.

If your question is "will I be able to transform the card in a mono-white deck", the answer is yes. The Phyrexian green mana symbol on Tarkir Duneshaper can be paid with {G} or 2 life. You can choose to pay 2 life and pay the remaining {4} with white mana.

Comment: Or there are all sorts of ways to generate green mana in a mono-white deck anyway.