Can i use assassins creed or doctor who land cards with any card?
Can i use assassins creed or doctor who land cards with any card? I want to create my own 250 card deck but I don't know if any and all land cards are allowed??

does this answer your question? https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/54037/how-does-color-identity-work-in-commander

Nope. Just really need to know if I can just use any land associated with the colour

As a general rule, dont use more cards than you need to for a format, usually you want exactly 60. It's something a lot of new players fall into, but bigger is very much not better in deck size, bigger is less consistent, less likely to give you what you need when you need it.

Yes, you can use any land in your deck, as long as it's format-legal.
Since in the comments you clarified that you play "kitchen table" Magic, meaning there are no real limitations to deck building, you can of course use any card you like in your deck.
When you start playing official formats, only cards from certain sets are allowed in your deck. However, if a card from a certain set is legal in the format you want to play, you may include it in your deck, even if that specific print of the card comes from another, illegal set. The only thing that matters here is the English name of the card.

206.4. Players may include cards from any printing in their constructed decks if those cards appear in sets allowed in that format (or those cards are specifically allowed by the Magic: The Gathering Tournament Rules). See the Magic: The Gathering Tournament Rules for the current definitions of the constructed formats (WPN.Wizards.com/en/resources/rules-documents).


Is it any deck? Because I don't know what I'm building. I wanted a mixture so I don't really know what makes it commander. I just know I want a 250 card deck.

I assumed you asked about Commander because the AC and Doctor Who are Commander sets. Do you play any official format? Or is it "kitchen table" magic, meaning no restrictions at all?

Kitchen table atm but I want to compete once I have learnt all the cards so I just want to know the rules. Plus we go by the rules at the Kitchen table lol

Not just land cards, you can use any card thats format legal. For example brcause Assassin's Trophy was in Murders at Karlov Manor, the Assassin's creed copy is legal in Standard.

@CaptainHades a commander deck is an exactly 100 card singleton deck, with one legendary creature (or two for partners or backgrounds) that start outside the deck and set the colors of the deck.  Any symbol or land type on cards in the rest of the deck can only be those colors. Its the most popular magic the gathering format.

Ahhh alright. So as long as the colour matches the land card you can use it?
